# Can't define Network when creating Instance Group with Go client library?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

When creating an unmanaged instance group through GCP Console, I can see the REST request as:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-east1-d/instanceGroups
{
  "name": "ig-web",
  "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/global/networks/nomad-network",
  "namedPorts": [
    {
      "name": "http",
      "port": 11080
    }
  ]
}
```

However, [according to the API docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instanceGroups) and [client library generated code](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1#InstanceGroup), one has no way to set the `network` URL.

Anyone care to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a documentation bug. The following will work:

```
op, err := gce.service.InstanceGroups.Insert(projectID, zone, &compute.InstanceGroup{
        Name:       name,
        NamedPorts: namedPorts,
        Network:    networkURL}).Do()
```